# MARS - MIPS - Recursive Binary Search stuck in loop

Tags: assembly, mips, binary-search-tree, mars-simulator

```
# MIPS Binary Search Algorithm w/ Arrays

.data

array:  .space 404
p1: .asciiz "\nEnter the data for a sorted array: "
p2: .asciiz "\nEnter a value to search for:  "
p3: .asciiz " is not found"
p4: .asciiz " is found at "

.text

main:

la  $s0, array  # s0 = addr of first int
addi    $t0, $zero, 0   # t0 = 0 counter
addi    $s1, $zero, 0   # s1 = 0 array size counter

#Store Array Values
store:

li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
la  $a0, p1     # address of string to print
syscall         # print the first prompt

li  $v0, 5      # system call for read_int
syscall         # read int to store

beq $v0, 0, searchP # once sentinel val hit, go to search   
j   storeVal    # store int in array if !=0

storeVal:

add     $t1, $zero, $t0 #offset in t1
add     $t1, $t1, $t1   #t1*2
add     $t1, $t1, $t1   #t1*4
add     $s2, $t1, $s0   #array with offset in s2
sw  $v0, 0($s2) #save int
addi    $t0, $t0, 1 # counter++
addi    $s1, $s1, 1 # array size counter++
lw  $t9, ($s0)  # loads addr of array
add $t9, $t9, $s0   # goes to addr of end of array
sub $t9, $t9, 4 # goes back 4 to beginning of last array val
j   store       # continue to add integers


#Binary Search
searchP:
li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
la  $a0, p2     # address of string to print
syscall         # print the second prompt

li  $v0, 5      # system call for read_int
syscall         # read int to find
move    $a0, $v0    # store int to find

beq $a0, 0, end # once sentinel val hit, go to end prog

la  $a1, array  # a1 = addr of first int
add $a2, $a1, $t9   # a2 = addr of last int

bsearch:

subu    $sp, $sp, 4 # 4 bytes 4 stack
sw  $ra, 4($sp) # save return addr

subu    $t0, $a2, $a1   # size of array
bnez    $t0, searchVal  # if not 0, search

move    $v0, $a1    # addr of only entry
lw  $t0, ($v0)  # load entry
beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
j   notFound    # not found


searchVal:
sra $t0, $t0, 3 # comp offset of middle m:
sll $t0, $t0, 2 # t0 = 4(t1/8)
addu    $v0, $a1, $t0   # middle m
lw  $t0, ($v0)  # t0 = m
beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
blt $a0, $t0, left  # search left
j   right       # search right

right:
addu    $a1, $v0, 4 # search right
jal bsearch
beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
j   notFound    # not found


left:
move    $a2, $v0    # search left of m
jal     bsearch
beq $a0, $t0, found # if = to int, print found
j   notFound    # not found

#Print
found:
li  $v0, 1      # system call code for print_int
move    $a0, $s2    # integer to print (counter)
syscall         # print it

li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
la  $a0, p4     # address of string to print
syscall         # print the answer part 2

j   searchP     # continue to search for more integers

notFound:
li  $v0, 1      # system call code for print_int
move    $a0, $s2    # integer to print (counter)
syscall         # print it

li  $v0, 4      # system call code for print_str
la  $a0, p3     # address of string to print
syscall         # print the answer part 2


j   searchP     # continue to search for more integers


#END PROG
end:

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

I finally got the array to accept inputs, however now my binary search is looping forever and it never hits the print statements. I feel like this has something to do with $t9 (in storeVal:), and not correctly finding the end of the array, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that.

edit: entering 1,2,3,4,5,0 works for the array, searching for 1 or 2 both return '268501008 is found at '. Searching for 3 sends it into an infinite loop... still not sure where I'm messing up.

Comment: `bsearch:

la  $a2, array  # a1 = addr of first int
la  $a2, ($t9)  # a2 = addr of last int` already doesn't look promising.

Comment: updated code and I'm getting new errors now, lot closer though.. I think